# Is there any algorithm which take O(1) time?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am looking for algorithm which take `O(1)` time for both `search and insertion`.

Is there any algorithm available? Is it possible?

Comment: Um, hash table?..

Comment: Algorithm to do **what**?

Comment: But insertion time in hash table is O(n) in worst case.

Comment: @Muhammad Umair: That's not necessarily true. If you have either linear probing or separate chaning hash table and resize it as it grows, then insertion takes ammortized O(1) time.

Comment: No, insertion time can be O(n): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Perfect_hash_function

Comment: @tjameson No. See your citation. "Perfect hashing allows for constant-time lookups in the worst case". That's O(1).

Comment: @EJP - Meant O(1)... mistyped the darn thing... and meant lookup is O(1) as well. Wow, not having a good day =/

Comment: I can't believe my answer got -3 votes. FIll you array or hashtable with as many elements as there are particles in the universe, then tell me it is O(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can theoretically have a O(1) insert and search for a hash map, assuming the hash is perfect, and the time to calculate the hash is O(1).

Comment: Unless a hashmap will be overflowed with data to put into his data structure.

Answer (score -3):

It is not possible. Reading the keys on which you will insert will be best O(log n) since the key has to be represented in binary. So each time you double the size, you will need to add an extra binary digit to the key, and so it will not be O(1). Let alone actually inserting the value.

Unless we are talking quantum computing?

Comment: Computers read words 16 or 32 bits at a time. Your logic eludes me.

Comment: Or 64 bits. What has this got to do with O(...) ?

Comment: O(1) implies constant amount of time to insert into any size collection. Double the collection size and it has no effect on time. But each time I double the collection size I need a longer key to represent an item in the collection. To read the key is O(n) on the key, and the key is proportional to log(m) the number of items in the collection.

Comment: A perfect hash is 32 or 64 bits and it is read by the processor in a single operation.

Comment: You are technically right, but in a way not usually useful to actual programmers.  The size of the key/pointer/struct is considered fixed even if this implies a theoretical limit on `n` of the kind you describe.  You can extend the argument to say that since 32-bit pointers limit you to 4 billion objects in memory all x86 sorting algorithms are `O(1)`, but don't be surprised if the software engineers think you're being obtuse.

Comment: I guess another way of looking at it is this: software people are ok saying that an implementation has `O(n)` behavior and a limit on `n` of 4 billion even though this is arguably a contradiction.